# Proving using Bernoulli inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I'm trying to prove this: $$0.99^n \le 1/2,\text{ for }n=100$$

I tried Bernoulli's inequality $(1-0.01)^n \geq 1-n\cdot0.01$ and it gave me LHS $\geq0$.

I also tried to do this: $((1-0.01)^n)^n \leq(1-1/2)^n$ and it gave me LHS $\geq-99$ and RHS $\geq49$.

Now I'm stuck.

Comment: The inequality is not true in general. It is true for $n\ge 69$. The Bernoulli-approximation gives $1-0.01n\le 0.5$ which gives $n\ge 50$ as a (weak) lower bound

Comment: Note that $0.99^n\le 0.5$ implies $1-0.01n\le 0.5$ because of $1-0.01n\le 0.99^n$

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{99}\right)^n \geq 1 +\frac{n}{99}$$
for every $n\geq 1$.  In particular, 
$$\frac{1}{0.99^{100}}=\left(1+\frac{1}{99}\right)^{100}\geq 1+\frac{100}{99}>2\,.$$

Comment: Isn't it $(1-\frac{1}{100})^n ≥ 1-\frac{n}{100}$?

Comment: @TobyMak  What do you mean?  Your inequality is correct (for $n\geq 1$), but it is not helpful.

Comment: I get why you started with $(1+\frac{1}{99})^n$ now. Can you explain how does $\frac{1}{0.99^{100}} = (1+\frac{1}{99})^{100}$?

Comment: @TobyMak Hmmm???  It is well known that $0.99=\frac{99}{100}$.

Comment: Thanks, everything's clear now. I just find the extremely abbreviated style you write in confusing. Maybe I need more practice, but that's just what I think.

Comment: @TobyMak Right, to leave the OP some things to think about instead of spoon-feeding them, the ultimate sin.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:
$$0.99^{100}<\frac12 \iff 2\cdot 99^{100}<100^{100} \iff \\
2\cdot 99^{100}<(1+99)^{100}=1+100\cdot 99+\cdots +100\cdot 99^{99}+99^{100} \iff \\
2\cdot 99^{100}<1+9900+\cdots+(1+99)\cdot 99^{99}+99^{100}\iff \\
2\cdot 99^{100}<1+9900+\cdots+99^{99}+2\cdot 99^{100}.$$